How to recover per-line git blame history after line endings were changed to CR?
Multiple developers have contributed to a project over few years.
A few commits ago one commit has changed the line endings in a single file from our standard LF (0x10) to CR (0x13). Reason unknown.
git log -p -- filename command shows that in every recent commit 1 line was removed, 1 was added. The line is the whole file content with ^M symbols in place of line breaks.
Smart code editors like VSCode are still able to display the code correctly broken into lines. GitLens "File history" correctly shows diff introduced by a commit. But per-line blame is not available.
I can fix line endings back to LF with VSCode (two clicks), but after that I will be blamed for every single line in the file.
Seems feasible to fix this by manually walking through each commit, recovering its diff and somehow manually attributing changed lines blame to the commit author. Kind of re-playing the changes, but with proper line endings.

How to recover per-line authors, taking some old commit as a starting point, and applying the diffs from every commit since the line endings were broken?

There's an option to ignore specific commits when assigning blame.

Thank you @jthill. Following your suggestion I read an article on --ignore-rev switch and the .git-blame-ignore-revs file. My task is not to skip certain commits or hide my formatting change, but to recover and re-build the per line blame, which is lost due to bad formatting earlier.

"A few commits ago one commit has changed the line endings in a single file from our standard LF (0x10) to CR (0x13). Reason unknown." Well you shouldn't have let that happen. The train has now left the station. This may be one of those rare situations where it is necessary to rebase that commit out of existence (or replace it by a commit that doesn't do that). Everyone will have to throw away their clones and clone again after the fix is made. Gosh, maybe even that wouldn't fix the blame problem.

use git blame -w.

git blame -w attributes every line to the last editor of the file: as from GIT point of view every small edit changes the whole file content. With ^M line breaks, git considers the file consisting of a single line. That is the problem.

found this script that fixes EOL problem and history
https://github.com/eantoranz/conflict_book/blob/main/scripts/correct_eol.sh
In-detail article: http://www.ezconflict.com/en/conflictsse16.html
But this solution doesn't work for the multi-developers project after problem commits were merged, many commtis and branches ago.
So I guess, I'll just fix the file, and declare the per-line blame lost.

This sounds more like you want to rewrite the commit history with line breaks fixed. Such an awful change should have been caught by review.

To do this locally,
mkdir -p .git/info
echo "* diff=crnl" >.git/info/attributes
git config diff.crnl.textconv "sed -Ez 's,\r\n?,\n,g'"

which will cause any Git-controlled diff run in that particular repo to first translate Mac or Windows newlines to Unix newlines.
The wildcard pattern might be reaching too far, if you've got binaries checked in you'll want to come up with a better set of matching patterns.
edit: testcase:
sh -x <<\EOD
cd `mktemp -d`; git init
seq 5 >file; git add .; git commit -am-
sed 1s,^,x, -i file; git commit -am1x
tr \\n \\r <file | tee file; git commit -am croops
sed s,5,x5, -i file; git commit -am5x
git blame file
mkdir -p .git/info; echo '* diff=crnl' >.git/info/attributes
git config diff.crnl.textconv "sed -Ez 's,\r\n?,\n,g'"
git blame file
EOD


Thank you for the advanced solution! I have to learn about the diff algorithms in git. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_setting_the_internal_diff_algorithm
